# Where are kali linux user files stored when installed using win-kex on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, kali-linux, wsl2

I am searching for the user's files in kali linux so I can transfer them to my windows machine. I have also spent an hour at least combing through my AppData folder in windows 10 but with no luck. If anyone has any idea where I could access the virtual kali file system, I would greatly appreciate it!

I have checked this path so far: C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local but with no luck. I have tried putting a unique file that only exists on kali and searching my entire machine for it but that does not work.

Is this a wsl2 problem?

**EDIT:**

This is what I found in my WindowsApps folder:

[image]

And inside each of those I find:
[image]

In C:\Users*YOURUSERHERE*\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState I find this(the only file that has kali linux in it):

[image]
and inside I find this:

[image]
with nothing in most of the folders.

Another update:

[image]

gets me:

[image]

Comment: They should be within the appropriate folder within WindowsApps within Program Files

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question with my findings

Comment: Do you mean the OS files or the files you're creating within your Kali home directory?

Comment: @LayneBernardo Sorry, the files I am creating...like if I write a text file or something. I updated the question again to include that bit of information.

Comment: I installed Win-Kex from this long document (https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex/#install-kali-linux-in-wsl2) and all the steps therein. There are no files per se yet but the folder c:\users\me..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps  and there is data there. Similar it appears to your edited post.  Now recall Kali in WSL is just for Linux command (as I understand WSL) . I also have a full fledged Kali machine Hyper-V with all the functionality.

Comment: The user filesystem (for WSL Ubuntu, at least) is stored in a virtual hard drive (.vhdx) file under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\ `. In my case, with Ubuntu, it's `C:\Users\*YOURUSERHERE*\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState`. Windows 10 has built in tools to mount this type of virtual drive, so you can just right-click it and click "mount". Make sure WSL isn't running when you mount it or it will fail. %LOCALAPPDATA% is your `C:\Users\*YOURUSERHERE*\AppData\Local` folder, but you can paste that directly into the file manager path and it will work.

Comment: @LayneBernardo It looks like this is the data for the Kali Linux launcher from the Microsoft store, not the kali user's account data.

Comment: What happens when you run WSL from the Windows Start button?  You should get a dialogue box, and I clicked on Open (because Kali is the only WSL system I have) and Kali opened.   Prompt is [/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32]  .  DIR in the Kali system just shows me EXE , DLL and like files for running the Linux commands it can.

Comment: I see instead:  This is a minimal install of Kali Linux - so I am in Linux. I did the update but I need to find that as well

Comment: Hmm, well the files should be on that virtual disk, although even if you mount it in Windows it probably won't be able to read the EXT4 file system. If you just want specific files, WSL does have access to your Windows partition under `/mnt/c/`. So you can just `cp ~/myfile /mnt/c/Users/*YOURUSER*`. You do have to actually click into the LocalState folder to find your VHDX file btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filesystems for WSL2 instances are stored in `.vhdx` files in the package directory (look in `LocalState` for `ext4.vhdx`).  Those are virtual disks, so that's why you don't see the individual files that you placed in the filesystem when you search in Windows.

However, WSL2 does provide an easy way to get at the ext4 filesystem from within Windows.  Go to `\\wsl$\` and you should find a directory named after your distribution (probably `\\wsl$\kali-linux` if using the defaults).  Inside there you should find your entire kali filesystem, and the files you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me!

Comment: Retracted previous statement, \\wsl$\ works for me too with Ubuntu when WSL is not running.

Comment: @LayneBernardo I'm sorry. I really tried. Wish I could have excepted you answer. I can at least upvote your comments...  :)

Comment: @Layne-Bernado The WSL instance does need to be *started* (see `wsl -l -v`) in order for it to appear.  But you can exit the shell and it will still be there until you terminate it (`wsl --terminate <distroname>`) or shutdown the subsystem (`wsl --shutdown`).

Comment: @LayneBernardo and NotTheDr01ds Is there a way I could save the storage in the wsl in another drive. Lets say I have two SSDs and one is a 2 terrabyte and I want kali on that one. Could I just drag and drop the wsl folder into my 2 terrabyte drive from my small one?

Comment: Ah that explains it. 
@Cyclist No worries I'm just being dumb. Yeah you should be able to copy files directly, I don't think you can move them like that though.

Comment: It's not quite as easy as dragging-and-dropping.  Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067679/11810933) for details on how to do it.  The answer uses Ubuntu as the example, but I've done the same thing with Kali.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Will this work? I am only asking because it's a little more simple of an answer...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580420/wsl-using-a-wsl-symlink-folder-from-windows

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's *quite* what you are looking for, but maybe.  Do you want to move the entire kali virtual disk to another drive or do you just want to move some files to another drive?  For "files" you could just link (as in that answer), but you can also just access the secondary drive under kali in `/mnt/d`.  The biggest problem with that is that WSL2 file access on an NTFS drive is *much* slower than the ext4 virtual disk/partition.  We're talking it could take minutes to work on a large git repository (due to the large number of small files).  To be continued ...

Comment: Even a link won't save you from that poor performance, as the real file would still be on the "slow" NTFS filesystem.

Comment: But ... that answer did give me an idea.  Is it possible to create a link of the *entire* `vhdx` on another drive?  Probably, but I'm not sure anyone has tested that.  I'll give it a quick shot tomorrow to see if it works initially, unless you get to it first.  That said, it's probably going to require another question so that the steps could be written out in an answer -- Comments don't work well for that (as my multi-comment response here is pushing the limits already).

Comment: Looks like [someone has tried the mklink method](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/412#issuecomment-680837524) and it seems to be fine.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'll have to check this out! Thanks!

Comment: For anyone coming across this later, note that there is also now a report in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1628969/1210833) that linking may not always be an error-free process.  Not sure yet if perhaps the instance was still in use when the move was done.  Before trying this, I definitely recommend (a) doing a `wsl --shutdown` before exporting or moving any WSL images (b) still doing a `wsl --export` as an extra backup